# Can't we make seperate file for checking login status which includes session_start() at the top and call wherever necessary?

Tags: php

What I did is created a php code to check login status (file name:login_status):

```
<?php
session_start()
// code body to check if session or cookies are set
// If not, then variable $loggedin = false, else true
// if true then redirect to profile page
// if false then redirect to login page
?>
```

But when I include this file above any code using `include_once("login_status.php");`, then php script stops execution `(if $loggedin == false)` instead of redirecting to login page and if`$loggedin == true` the redirect it to profile page.

What I did is, instead of using `include_once("login_status.php");`, I simple copied the code of `login_status` above any page where I need it. After that its working fine.

I am not able to figure it out what does include_once makes a difference?

However, its true that `session_start()` should be on the top, before anything. But does `include_once` makes any difference on that?

Comment: <?php
    session_start()
    // code body to check if session or cookies are set
    // If not, then variable $loggedin = false, else true
    // if true then redirect to profile page
    // if false then redirect to login page
    ?>

Comment: try posting the actual code you're using in your question so people can help you

Comment: that is the code for checking login status, i dont know why it didn't appear in my question

Comment: Including the script should not make a difference. But see [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) for some debugging hints. That's what you seem to hint at.

Comment: @mario: Ya I think you are right. That may be the reason. I have to go through the code to debug it with the help of link you provided . Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Also, since it's important that the login check takes place, you should probably be using `require_once` rather than `include_once`.

Answer (score 0):

> its true that session_start() should be on the top, before anything.

Not before anything, but *before any output*.

Also, please, make yourself familiar with error reporting and make appropriate settings to be able either see errors on-screen(on a development server) or logged (on a production) - so, there would be no need for *guess* anything.

on a development server make changes in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

production

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
```